# What does the "bonus" tag over the score in NBA games means?

Tags: rules, basketball, nba

Sometimes, while watching a NBA game, I see a "bonus" tag text over the telecast scoreboard.

What does it means? Which rule or set of rules influence this?

Comment: the "duplicate" answer is related to college basketball only, not NBA.

Comment: The *question* is the same. Maybe it needs a better answer, but that's not a reason for having a new question.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question, the title on the original question doesn't make it easier to find too.

Comment: That's true. Your question will help with that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The "bonus" tag occurs when one team accumulates a limited number of fouls.
Each subsequent foul results in free throws.

Please see [a wikipedia article here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonus_%28basketball%29) for more details.